# Clustering algorithm to cluster objects based on their relation weight

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have n words and their relatedness weight that gives me a n*n matrix. I'm going to use this for a search algorithm but the problem is I need to cluster the entered keywords based on their pairwise relation. So let's say if the keywords are {tennis,federer,wimbledon,london,police} and we have the following data from our weight matrix:

```
            tennis  federer  wimbledon  london  police      
tennis        1       0.8       0.6       0.4     0.0
federer       0.8      1        0.65      0.4     0.02
wimbledon     0.6     0.65       1        0.08    0.09
london        0.4     0.4       0.08        1      0.71
police        0.0     0.02      0.09      0.71     1
```

I need an algorithm to to cluster them into 2 clusters : {tennis,federer,wimbledon} {london,police}. Is there any know clustering algorithm than can deal with such thing ? I did some research, it appears that K-means algorithm is the most well known algorithm being used for clustering but apparently K-means doesn't suit this case.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please describe by which criteria you want to create this clusters? Why wimbledon and london are not in one cluster?

Comment: If your matrix is positive semidefinite, you could use kernel K-means.

Comment: @StanislavLevental, I guess that the reason is the low `weight' in the respective cell of the matrix above which I interpret as a similarity matrix.

Comment: @StanislavLevental as Per explained it's because of its low 'weight'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [DBSCAN](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.71.1980). If it suits your needs, you might wish to take a closer look at an optimised version, [TI-DBSCAN](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13529-3_8), which uses triangle inequality for reducing spatial query cost.

DBSCAN's advantages and disadvantages are [discussed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=DBSCAN&oldid=463377531#Advantages). It splits input data to a set of clusters whose cardinality isn't known *a priori*. You'd have to transform your similarity matrix into a distance matrix, for example by taking `1 - similarity` as a distance.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat it as a network clustering problem. With a recent version of mcl software (http://micans.org/mcl), you can do this (I've called your example fe.data).

```
mcxarray  -data fe.data -skipr 1 -skipc 1 -write-tab fe.tab -write-data fe.mci -co 0 -tf 'gq(0)' -o fe.cor
   # the above computes correlations (put in data file fe.cor) and a network (put in data file fe.mci).
   # below proceeds with the network.
mcl fe.mci -I 3 -o - -use-tab fe.tab
   # this outputs the clustering you expect. -I is the 'inflation parameter'. The latter affects
   # cluster granularity. With the default parameter 2, everything ends up in a single cluster.
```

Disclaimer: I wrote mcl and a slew of associated network loading/conversion and analysis programs recently rebranded as 'mcl-edge'. They all come together in a single software package. Seeing your example made me curious whether it would be doable with mcl-edge, so I quickly tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this book on Information retrieval

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering-1.html

it explains very well what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Your weights are higher for more similar words and lower for more different words. A clustering algorithm requires similar points/words to be closer spatially and different words to be distant. You should change the matrix `M` into `1-M` and then use *any* clustering method you want, including k-means.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a distance matrix, it seems a shame not to try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_linkage_clustering. By hand, I think you get the following clustering:

((federer, tennis), wimbledon) (london, police)

The similarity for the link that joins the two main groups (either tennis-london or federer-london) is smaller than any of the similarities that build the two groups: london-police, tennis-federer, and federer-wimbledon: this characteristic is guaranteed by single linkage clustering, since it binds together closest clusters at each stage, and the two main groups are linked by the last binding found.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN (see other answers) and successors such as OPTICS are clearly an option.

While the examples are on vector data, all that the algorithms need is a distance function. If you have a similarity matrix, that can trivially be used as distance function.

The example data set probably is a bit too small for them to produce meaningful results. If you just have this little of data, any "hierarchical clustering" should be feasible and do the job for you. You then just need to decide on the best number of clusters.